# Name angular dynamic created scope with model name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i want to create scope with dynamic name

eg.

```
  <div ng-repeat="id in ides">
         < .... ng-model="id.eId">
  </div>
```

now i wan to create and display my n (size of ides) scopes.
eg like

```
<div>
      <span>{{scopevalue"id.eId".name}}</span>
</div>
```

how can this be done with angular

Comment: I don't understand what your are looking for, for example id.eId contains "No1", you want to access scopevalueNo1 variable ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use bracket notation in this case. For example like this (define `$scope.names = {};` in controller too):

```
<div ng-repeat="id in ides">
    <input type="text" ng-model="names[id.eId].name" />
</div>
```

and then you can do

```
<div>
     <span>{{names[id.eId].name}}</span>
</div>
```